# Why is universal newlines mode deprecated in Python?

Tags: python, io, deprecation

I just noticed that the [universal newline](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) feature of file operations seems to be on its way out.

The documentation for Python 3.5 [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open)'s `mode` parameter indicates that it's deprecated:

> `'U'`     universal newlines mode (deprecated)

At least as far back as Python 3.2, [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#open) contains a similar "backwards compatibility only" warning when documenting the usage of the `mode` argument:

> `'U'`     universal newlines mode (for backwards compatibility; should not be used in new code)

Even in Python 2.7, a similar warning is placed in the documentation of [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open).

What's the reason for this?

Comment: The logic behind this is fairly simple. It's considered more "Pythonic" to have named things rather than unnamed things. So you use a named parameter rather than a character flag. The flag idea is very much a leftover of Python's C implementation and it's small wonder that it's being weeded out.

Comment: Because files are opened in universal newline mode by default.

Comment: The `U` flag to `open`'s `mode` parameter is deprecated in Python 3.3 and [removed entirely in Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#porting-to-python-3-11)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open) in the Python 3 library  has a `newline` argument.  Setting it to `None` enables universal newlines.  This is the accepted way to do it, rendering the `mode='U'` argument redundant.

Use `newline=None` to enable universal newlines mode (this is the default).

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood. I read it as saying that universal newlines in general were being deprecated, not just the mode character. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 12):

After stumbling across this question, I updated the documentation to be clearer about what's going on (https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11646/files).

The confusingly cryptic table entry for `'U'` is gone, and instead there's a paragraph further down that states:

> There is an additional mode character permitted, `'U'`, which no longer
> has any effect, and is considered deprecated. It previously enabled
> :term:`universal newlines` in text mode, which became the default behaviour
> in Python 3.0. Refer to the documentation of the
> :ref:`newline <open-newline-parameter>` parameter for further details.

Note: as of Python 3.11, this paragraph is no longer present in the docs, as the long-deprecated option has now been removed entirely.

Comment: An answer that references an upstream patch in the docs by the author - the right way for stackexchanges to work.  Kudos @ncoghlan.

Comment: @ncoghlan It's still confusing and some what untechnical. In which mode are the newlines kept, if I need them to roundtrip? Does this mean, I need to read the text file as binary, if I want to keep the original newlines, then UTF-8 decode to a string, and then write it back as binary? 

IMHO it's too restrictive. Other script languages have ways to DWIM (Do What I Mean).

Comment: @HelmutWollmersdorfer `newline=''` is likely the option you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144382/preserve-end-of-line-style-when-working-with-files-in-python